# Multi-dimension array sort by price Ascending and descending

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

This is the following array i am getting...! how could I sort it.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 29.99
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 22.40
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 12.95
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 9.60
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 8.16
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 7.66
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 7.19
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 7.14
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

        )
```

**As you can see in index 2 array is not sorted beacuse 5.10 should on index [1] and 4.79 on index [2]**

```
[2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 5.99
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 4.79
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 5.10
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 4.20
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 4.08
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 4.00
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 3.20
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 3.19
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 2.86
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 3.58
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 2.82
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [price] => 2.90
                    [params] => 
                    [text] => demotext
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value

Comment: What is the result that you expect?

Comment: http://m.partysavvy.co.uk/first-birthday/boy-themes/fun-at-one-boy?prc=h2l

If you open above URL you will see the sort high to low is not prefect, so i need to sort it prorperly, For e.g look the price of product "Fun At One Boy Baseball Cap"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $arr is your array then try:

```
foreach($arr as &$ar){
  foreach($ar as $key=>$r){
    $price[$key] = $r['price'];
    $params[$key] = $r['params'];
    $text[$key] = $r['text'];
  }
 array_multisort($price, SORT_DESC, $params, SORT_REGULAR, $text,SORT_REGULAR,$ar);
}
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/94599)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use array_multisort() for that
http://ch2.php.net/array_multisort

Answer (score 0):

Try using array_multisort function https://www.php.net/array_multisort

Answer (score 0):

This what I sorted after great fuss , to break multi-dimension array into One Array and then sorted it according to price.

```
$array = your array;
// merging multi-dimension array into one array.
$result = array_merge_recursive($array[0],$array[1],$array[2],$array[3],$array[4]);
// now Sort array according to price
array_multisort($result, SORT_ASC);
foreach ($result as $key => $val) {
   foreach ($val as $new) { 
   }
echo  $new;
  }
```